# view relationships issue in D7

Tags: 7, views

I have a node type that contains a field with several data items (read also).

I need to display 4 items related to the viewed article. The default is to display the field which gives the titles but we also need the images of that articles.

I created a view to get the nid from the contextual filters and panels sends it. Then a relationship with the read also field [require relationship, delta => 1]. It shows the title and image but it also shows the title of the current viewed node as block title which we don't need.

Comment: You can change the block title in the view or from the blocks admin interface.  But I'm assuming you know that and that your question is something else I'm not quite getting.  Could you add a screenshot or something else that illustrates your problem a little further?

Comment: thanks a lot i figured out my issue and solved as u mentioned and it was some misunderstanding of relationships